# Tabulated lists of examples

Tags: english, corpora, germanic-languages, online-resources, german

"Everybody [?] knows" that there are these pairs of corresponding words in German and English in which an "f" appears in German where a "p" appears in English:

> Bischoff, bishop
>
> Schiff, ship
>
> offen, open
>
> hoffen, hope

(The initial letters of German nouns are capital.)

My question is whether some book or web page has tabulated a moderately comprehensive list of examples of this, and of other similar phenomena?

Comment: This is a phenomenon of the sogenannte ["Second Sound Shift"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_German_consonant_shift) in High German languages. English, like Plattdeutsch and Nederlands, is a Low German language. The terms refer to altitude, not social status; High German languages are spoken towards the Alps in the South of the German-speaking area, and Low German languages are spoken in the plains to the North.

Comment: . . . I neglected "schlafen" and "sleep".

Comment: . . . "Apfel" and "apple" are a slightly more complicated example.

Comment: . . . and "Waffe" and "weapon".

Comment: So does anybody publish books of tables or something like that listing instances of this phenomenon and others that are amenable to tabulation?

Comment: . . . then there's the question of what to make of German "Grab" versus English "grave".  This time it's German that has the plosive consonant where English has a fricative, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Dutch kopen = German kaufen. Sap = saft. Aap = Affe. Lopen = laufen. Op = auf. Roepen = rufen.  Etc. etc., there are countless examples.

Comment: . . . and scharf/sharp, helfen/help . . .